# Storing resources in IsolatedStorage for windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I'm writing a small game for Windows Phone 7.
It's a vocabulary based game, I have a text dictionary which is basically a huge text file with a large number of words.

How can I use this with the emulator. I found that we can only access files that our app creates with IsolatedStorage. Should I be manually creating this file each time the app loads(This isn't a feasible approach) or can I somehow bundle the text file with the application. In the latter case how can I access this file.

Just to be clear I'm not looking for links to tutorials for Isolated Storage.
I want to add that text file to my project resources and copy that to IsolatedStorage. I don't know how to do this, if someone could help me with this, it'd be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact when you use the emulator, you can use the isolatedStorage, but if you quit the emulator, the isolatedStorage is deleted.

So, what you have to do, is to not quit the emulator, to let the file in the IsolatedStorage, but you can exit the application.

---

How to write a txt file from content to isolatedStorage

```
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();


        Stream yourFilepath = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("YourFilePath.txt", UriKind.Relative)).Stream;
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(yourFilepath);


        Stream yourIsolatedPath = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("YourFileIsolatedPath.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, myIsolatedStorage);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(yourIsolatedPath);


        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
        }
```

This code must be placed in the function

```
    private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

In App.xaml.cs

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. 
It's not feasible for me to create the text file from within the program. I want the file automatically copied into the IsolatedStorage when I run the application.